# Inserting CTE results into temp table generates duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a long series of CTEs, and I want to insert the results into a temporary table at the end.  However, I am ending up with 16 rows of duplicate data instead of just the one.  Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO #lvl_1_results
    (
        [Level_1]                       
      , [Level_0]                       
      , [P]
      , [Sim (%)]
      , [V]
      , [StAV (%)]
      , [CV]
      , [CV (%)]
      , [Sim (Mean)]
      , [SD]
      , [IAV]
      , [MAV]
      , [BMP]
      , [BMP (%)]
      , [BMV]
      , [BMV (%)]
      , [BMCV]
      , [BMCV (%)]
      , [Sim BMP (Mean)]
      , [BM SD]
      , [SAP]
      , [SAP (%)]
      , [ActV]
      , [ActV (%)]
      , [ACV]
      , [ACV (%)]
      , [Act (Mean)]
      , [Act SD]
      , [MV]
      , [MV (%)]
    )
        SELECT sc.[Level_1]
             , sc.[Level_0]
             , [P]
             , [P] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [V]
             , [V] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [CV]
             , [CV] / NULLIF([upper VaR], 0)
             , [Sim (Mean)]
             , [SD]
             , [IAV]
             , [MAV]
             , [BMP]
             , [BMP] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [BMV]
             , [BMV] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [BMCV]
             , [BMCV] / NULLIF([upper bm VaR], 0)
             , [Sim BMP (Mean)]
             , [BM SD]
             , [SAP]
             , [SAP] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [ActV]
             , [ActV] / NULLIF([MV], 0)
             , [ACV]
             , [ACV] / NULLIF([upper active VaR], 0)
             , [Act (Mean)]
             , [Act SD]
             , [MV]
             , [MV] / NULLIF([parent_MV], 0)
        FROM sc
           , s_p
           , s_v
           , bm_c
           , bm_v
           , bm_p
           , a_c
           , a_v
           , a_p
           , MV
           , upper_mv
           , c_l_v
           , bm_c_l_v
           , a_c_l_v
           , s_m
           , bm_m
           , a_m
           , sim_sd
           , bm_sd
           , a_sd
           , s_i
           , s_mar
```

How can I get this query to produce just one row?  For performance reasons, I think I should opt for a solution that doesn't just select the distinct rows.

Comment: You have several tables joined in FROM section but you didn't have the key columns to connect them. You might be having a cartesian product of all the  records.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Only 16 rows? So many of your tables are just empty. Check LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN and WHERE clauses, your query is missing it.

Comment: @Gordonlinoff do you make this recommendation to encourage use of left/inner/outer and hence force the user to supply an ON? Cause technically the "proper" join syntax equivalent of this format is CROSS APPLY and it will cause exactly the same Cartesian product.. I advocate ansi style joins too, just wondered if your intent was to make this user a better coder, as it won't necessarily solve his problem (I know you know that, but does he know that? Ahh..)

Comment: @CaiusJard: (i) Maybe CROSS JOIN and not CROSS APPLY.  (ii) Using INNER/LEFT/... JOIN will force SQL user to NOT forget join condition/join predicate: ... JOIN ... ON <join predicate> (that is mandatory for INNER JOIN / etc.)

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I thought sqlserver's way of doing cross join was CROSS APPLY because I seldom do CROSS JOIN in MsSQLS (though often in oracle), mostly its TVFs hence apply. Old age y see

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated in their comments, this query doesn't use the ansi JOIN syntax:

```
TableA
[INNER/LEFT] JOIN
TableB
ON
 TableA.id=tableb.id
```

The advantage of using this style is that you Must supply an ON clause which forces you to think about how the data in your tables is actually related

You havent told the database how this data is related at all, so all it has done is join every row it found, to every other row, giving every possible combination of rows

Because you're getting 16 rows, it implies that some of your tables have 2 or more rows. If 2 tables have 2 rows, then the result is 2x2x2x2 rows. (Or maybe two tables have 2 rows and one has 4, or maybe two tables have 4 rows.. or a 2 and an 8, either way, when multiplied so every row is joined to every other row, you're getting 16 rows)

If you have 2 tables that have values a,b and 1,2 and they're joined like you have done here the database will give you

```
a,1
a,2
b,1
b,2
```

These rows are all unique in themselves, but if you just selected the letter you'd see a a b b, and then complain there were duplicate letters. If you just look at the numbers the complaint would be the same

Add more tables in without any relationship between them, and it will get worse. Hopefully easy to see that adding another 2 row table with x and y would increase your results to 8 rows..

You have to tell your database which columns in which tables link the tables together. If you want to see which tables cause your duplicates, do a select *